# How to get button values inside a foreach using jquery and codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, foreach

In my view i have a foreach loop like below

```
<?php foreach($wishes as $wish) { ?>
    <input id="delete" type="button" value="<?= $wish->id ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

button value will be diffrent in each buttons

if I use a method like below it only take the first button click and its value other buttons do nothing

what did I do wrong

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#delete").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var id = $("#delete").val();

        console.log('delete');
        console.log(id);

    });

});
```

Comment: id MUST be unique in DOM.

Comment: id's will be 1,2,3,... likewise not the same id. using this button for delete table row in database but can only get first buttons id. other buttons not working

Comment: Not really, read your code again. id's of your buttons will be "delete", "delete", "delete"....

Comment: what can I do for this problem sir?

Comment: Take a look on Senal answer, use classes instead of id, and get element clicked value instead of trying to read a specific element.

Comment: use `class` or `data-id` instead of id!
as @Alexis said ID must be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use classes instead of ids. Because an id has to be unique. Since your id values are dynamic you can listen to the button click event by using the button's class.

```
<?php foreach($wishes as $wish) { ?>
   <input class="delete" type="button" value="<?= $wish->id ?>">
<?php } ?>

$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".delete").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      var id = $(this).val();
      console.log(id);

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php foreach($wishes as $wish) { ?>
   <input class="delete" type="button" value="<?= $wish->id ?>">
<?php } ?>
```

**Method 1**

Use class instead of id for click event

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".delete").click(function() {

      var IdValue = $(this).val();
      alert(IdValue);

  });

});
```

**Method 2**

Function can be call on button click `onclick="function_name()"` and pass the id as a parameter

```
<?php foreach($wishes as $wish) { ?>
   <input class="delete" type="button" value="<?= $wish->id ?>" onclick="GetId(<?= $wish->id ?>)" >
<?php } ?>

function GetId(IdValue){
    alert(IdValue)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

add to your code class for events

```
<?php foreach($wishes as $wish) { ?>
    <input id="<?= $wish->id ?>" class="action" type="button" >
<?php } ?>
```

`$wish->id`  --> id must be uniq, and server must provide this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".action").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var id = event.target.id;

        console.log('delete');
        console.log(id);

    });

});
```

Comment: Here id's will be duplicated too and same answer has been already posted

Comment: sorry, fixed :)

Comment: How can you be sure that OP data are not duplicated and whishes id haven't the same value ? Senal answer is a better way or use data-attributes for store this kind of data

Comment: it's not better, because id must be on id attribute, otherwise it's confusing, and id must validate on oniq on the server.

Comment: It's not, id attribute are used in DOM and usefull only if they're unique here you are not sure of you kind of data you have and not sure they are unique so using data-attribute for storing data on HTML element is highly better on a data-attribute instead of a HTML unique selector used to target HTML elements !

Comment: ok, but value can be same, and id for your situation match better then value. And i agree with data-attribute it's best solution